# Percussion score

Tags: musixtex, musixper

It is needed to replicate the following percussion score:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setname1{Percussion}
    \setclefsymbol1\drumclef
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac24}
    \parindent15mm
    \def\writebarno{\the\barno}
    %\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
    \scale{1.0}
    \startpiece 
    %1er compás
    \notes \loffset{2.8}{\zchar{12}{\metron{\qu}{74}}} 
    \ql j \ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j \en\bar
    \notes \ql j \en
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en\bar  
    %Rápido corro
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en\bar% barra
    %Voy silencio
    \notes \ql j \hsk \qp \en\bar
    %Corro ligerito
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j \en\bar
    %Corro rápido
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en
    \systemnumbers
    \alaligne
    %Corro sálto
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en
    \notes%Sálto
    \ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en\bar
    %Voy silencio
    \notes \ql j \hsk \qp \en\bar
    %Ligerito Ligerito
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j \en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j \en\bar 
    %Rápido sálto
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en
    \notes%Sálto
    \ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en\bar
    %Rápido rápido
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en\bar
    %Sálto voy
    \notes%Sálto
    \ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en
    \notes \ql j\hsk\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \Endpiece
  \end{music}
  
  
  \begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \systemnumbers
    %\setname1{Percusión}
    \setclefsymbol1\drumclef
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac34}
    \parindent0mm
    %\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
    \def\thebarno{\ifnum\barno=1\relax\else\the\barno\fi}%Descarta imprimir 1er numero del sistema
    \def\writebarno{\the\barno}
    %\def\writebarno{\llap{\thebarno\barnoadd}}
    %\scale{0.9}
    \startbarno=13
    \startpiece 
    %1er compás
    %Voy corro ligerito
    \notes \ql j \en
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en  
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j \en\bar
    %Voy silencio ligerito
    \notes \ql j \qp \en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j \en\bar
    %Sálto sálto ligerito
    \notes%Sálto
    \ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en
    \notes%Sálto
    \ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j \en\bar
    %Voy silencio corro
    \notes \ql j \qp \en
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en\bar  
    %Voy silencio rápido
    \notes \ql j \qp \en
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en\bar
    %Voy silencio corro
    \notes \ql j \qp \en
    \Notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\enotes
    \systemnumbers
    \alaligne\bar
    %Sálto sálto ligerito
    \notes%Sálto
    \ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en
    \notes%Sálto
    \ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j \en\bar
    %Voy silencio silencio
    \Notes \ql j \qp \qp \en\bar
    %Voy silencio ligerito
    \notes \ql j \qp \en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j \en\bar
    %Voy silencio rápido
    \notes \ql j \qp \en
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en\bar
    %Voy voy ligerito
    \notes \ql j \ql j \en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j \en\bar
    %Voy silencio silencio
    %\notes\ql j\hsk\qp\hsk\qp\hsk\en
    \NOtes\ql j\qp\qp\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \Endpiece
  \end{music}
  

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current]

The desired output is as follow (note that the end bars should be aligned, also the fonts):
[image: desired]

Comment: I know nothign about musictex, so I can't help, but a suggestion: can you reduce the example so that it's *minimal*? I mean, with just two "rows" should be sufficient...

Comment: To align the bars you need to delete the spaces, especially after \notes and before \en. If you want a different key, you will need to choose another set of note type. For the numbers you can choose any suitable letter, and tell MusiXTex to use it before \the\barno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (just deleted the spaces, and configure the fonts):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}

\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \font\B=phvb8t at 9pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \setname1{Percussion}
    \setclefsymbol1\drumclef
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac24}
    \parindent15mm
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    %\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
    \scale{1.0}
    \startpiece 
    %1er compás
    \notes\loffset{2.8}{\zchar{12}{\metron{\qu}{\B74}}}\ql j\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en\bar
    \notes\ql j\en
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en\bar  
    %Rápido corro
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en\bar% barra
    %Voy silencio
    \notes\ql j\hsk\qp\en\bar
    %Corro ligerito
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %Corro rápido
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en
    \systemnumbers
    \alaligne
    %Corro sálto
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en
    %Sálto
    \notes\ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en\bar
    %Voy silencio
    \notes\ql j\hsk\qp\en\bar
    %Ligerito Ligerito
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en\bar 
    %Rápido sálto
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en
    %Sálto
    \notes\ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en\bar
    %Rápido rápido
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en\bar
    %Sálto voy
    %Sálto
    \notes\ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en
    \notes\ql j\hsk\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \Endpiece
  \end{music}
  
  
  \begin{music}
    \font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \nobarnumbers
    \systemnumbers
    %\setname1{Percusión}
    \setclefsymbol1\drumclef
    \generalmeter{\meterfrac34}
    \parindent0mm
    %\renewcommand*\writebarno{\textit{\the\barno}}%
    \def\thebarno{\ifnum\barno=1\relax\else\the\barno\fi}%Descarta imprimir 1er numero del sistema
    \def\writebarno{\A\the\barno}
    %\def\writebarno{\llap{\thebarno\barnoadd}}
    %\scale{0.9}
    \startbarno=13
    \startpiece 
    %1er compás
    %Voy corro ligerito
    \notes\ql j\en
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en  
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %Voy silencio ligerito
    \notes\ql j\qp\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %Sálto sálto ligerito
    %Sálto
    \notes\ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en
    %Sálto
    \notes\ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %Voy silencio corro
    \Notes\ql j \qp\en
    \notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\en\bar  
    %Voy silencio rápido
    \Notes\ql j\qp\en
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en\bar
    %Voy silencio corro
    \Notes\ql j\qp\en
    \Notes\ibl0j0\qb0{j}\tbl0\qb0j\enotes
    \systemnumbers
    \alaligne%\bar
    %Sálto sálto ligerito
    %Sálto
    \notes\ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en
    %Sálto
    \notes\ibl0j0\qbp0j%
    \roff{\tbbl0\tql0j}\sk\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %Voy silencio silencio
    \NOtes\ql j\qp\qp\en\bar
    %Voy silencio ligerito
    \Notes\ql j\qp\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %Voy silencio rápido
    \Notes\ql j\qp\en
    \notes\ibl1j0\qb1j\enotes
    \notesp\nbbl1\qb1j\enotes
    \Notes\tbl1\qb1j\en\bar
    %Voy voy ligerito
    \notes\ql j\ql j\en
    \notes\ibbl0k0\qb0{jjj}\tqb0j\en\bar
    %Voy silencio silencio
    %\notes\ql j\hsk\qp\hsk\qp\hsk\en
    \NOtes\ql j\qp\qp\en
    \setdoubleBAR
    \Endpiece
  \end{music}
  

\end{document}
```

The output is as follow:
[image: solved]